# jQuery Validate no Hyphens

Tags: jquery, validation

Hello I am using the jQuery Validation plugin to validate my HTML forms.

I have an input field that does not accept hyphens:

```
<label for="trackISRC"><span class="mandatory">*</span> Track ISRC:</label>
<input type="text" name="trackISRC" id="trackISRC" MAXLENGTH="12">
```

Now I have to find a way to make this field accept every type of character but NO hyphens using the jQuery validation plugin..

How can I do that?

This is an example of the jQuery validation plugin for rules:

```
$("#trackFile").rules("add", {
 accept: "mp3|WAV|MP3|wav"
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regexp for no hyphens:

```
"^[^\\-]*$"
```

Comment: ok but how do I integrate it with the jQuery validation plugin?

Comment: well, I think you already have an answer in your question - what is the `accept`? Regex, I think. then, initialize the validation plugin with the regex I provided and see if it helps. if not, then please create a sample jsfiddle with 2 fields - one working and the second you have to validate